# Consultar si existe un registro en tabla relacionada

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Es simple tengo estos modelos

```
class Capita extends Model
{

    

    public function socio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Socio', 'socio_id');
    }
   

}
```

y

```
class Socio extends Model
{
    public function capitas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Capita', 'socio_id')
        ->limit(12)
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    }


}
```

e intento

```
    public function create_all(Request $r)  
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();

        $user->acceso('data');

        $periodo = $r->input('mm') . $r->input('aaaa');

        $created_at = $r->input('aaaa') . '-' . $r->input('mm') . '-01';

        $socios = Socio::where('socios.baja', null)
        ->get();


        foreach ($socios as $s) {

            if($s->capitas->where('periodo',$periodo)->count() == 0) //esta es la condicional
            {
                $data[] = [

                    'socio_id' =>  $s->id,
                    'zona_id' => $s->zona_id,
                    'valor' => $s->cuota,
                    'periodo' => $periodo
                    
                ];
            }
        }


        $capita = new Capita();



        $insert = $capita->insert($data);



        if ($insert) {

            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'message-success' => 'Capitas Generadas. Total ' . count($data),
            
            ]);

        } else {

            return redirect()->back()
            ->with(['message-warning' => 'Ha ocurrido un error']);
        }
    }
```

El código funciona pero cuando le agregue el condicional paso a tardar mucho y x cada mes q se registran capitas tarda el doble.
El tema es que la condicional para ver si la cápita de este periodo ya existe hace que tarde un monton en ejecutar, pero necesito saber si esa cápita de ese mes ya existe.

Hay alguna manera que ya me traiga esos socios que no tienen la capita de ese mes (periodo) en la misma consulta de $socios = Socio:: ... ??

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor tu duda por favor, es decir lo que esperas obtener?

Comment: @BetaM en la ultima parte el OP pone "*me traiga esos socios que no tienen la capita de ese mes (periodo) en la misma consulta de $socios*" por lo que entiendo, quiere registros que no tengan ese periodo, si es asi, se puede usar `whereDoesntHave `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun lo que dices: *Hay alguna manera que ya me traiga esos socios que no tienen la capita de ese mes (periodo)*

Puedes usar `whereDoesntHave` para obtener lo que quieres, lo que hace esta funcion es poner un filtro personalizado a una relacion de lo que "no quieres" (su contra parte seria `whereHas`), en tu caso el filtro seria que no haya registros de un "periodo especifico", asi:

```
$data = Socio::whereDoesntHave('capitas', function ($query) use ($periodo) {
    $query->where('periodo', $periodo);
});
```

Con lo anterior, `$data` solo tendra los registros que no tenga el "periodo" que le envies

**Referencia**

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: Si es eso y hace lo que quiero pero tarda muchísimo mas la consulta, Igual lo voy a implementar xq optimiza el código y es mas prolijo. Gracias.